# Locating a file directory to display pdf in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, directory

I am having a problem with displaying a pdf in my form wen a menu item is clicked
the directory im using cant be found
the file is in the project folder

```
 private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\ColsTechieApp\\TechnicianApplicationUserManual.pdf");
        }
```

when i enter the full location

```
  private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\UV Chetty\Dropbox\Final\Complete\ColsTechieApp (Complete)\ColsTechieApp\Technician Application User Manual.pdf");
        }
```

it works how do i make the path exclusive to the project folder

Comment: Since the string is literal, the first example should be: `@"\\ColsTechieApp\TechnicianApplicationUserManual.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` as your current set and combin it with `Path.Combine`

Should work, becaus you are using full path

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory can change during the application lifetime, so it's not guaranteed to be the startup path of the application. Using the [StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) can be better, depending on what the user wants of course.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're trying to escape backslashes but the @ specifies that the string shouldn't be escaped. (Plus, you seem to be missing whitespaces)

Secondly, Environment.CurrentDirectory inserts the current path. Used with Path.Combine, you'll have your entire location. 
If you're really lazy, you can skip the Path.Combine and directly concatenate strings. Process.Start() probably converts it to a Path automatically.